# Can we build software for Android and the web using React once?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, web, ionic-framework, ionic-native

I mean you only code once and compile to Android app + web without extra additional customization.

And Can Ionic do the same ?

Answer (score 1):

Try looking into React Native, `https://reactnative.dev/`. Also, just a friendly tip: Before asking questions on Stack Overflow try doing your own research on the topic, you might find something. :)